# Low power low speed pulse divider?

Tags: frequency, low-power, pulse, counter, frequency-measurement

I have a digital input which receives irregular pulses. I want a circuit that takes that input and generates an output pulse for every 100 (or so) input pulse. The expected input speed is 10-300 Hz. I need to circuit to draw something like 1 uA max.

First, I was thinking of a simple binary counter, but the ICs I've found consume some 50 or 100 uA. Am I just looking at the wrong components or should I look for a different solution? Perhaps there are other ways to divide than to apply a counter?

[My digikey search](https://www.digikey.se/en/products/filter/counters-dividers/731?s=N4IgjCBcoGwJxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaIALAAxwDMdIAuoQA4AuUIAymwE4CWAOwDmIAL6E4MKohApIGHAWJkQtMAFYNMCMxDtOPASPGEATGaoB2WfMV5CJSOQAcIQmDPvwFb2BhMrByQIACSgmy4wri8piAAtF7QclB8AK7KTuQIhBpMEgm0tqm8GY6qYDKMBfEByfLpmapF1YTxCPUlZSrO4PkFdaD8ACac8ZUQQZzebACeLLic6NgoYmJAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get below 1μA, the 74LVC series is my choice. I could not find an 8 bit counter, but there is a [4-bit counter](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/counters-dividers/731?s=N4IgjCBcpgnAHLKoDGUBmBDANgZwKYA0IA9lANogAMIAugL7EC0ATMiGpAC4BOArkVIUQSBswAs7TljyCykSgHYArHXqMQANnYBLACZQQTMFQjEADl0MhiXAJ7n8hzLjTqgA). For example the [74LVC161](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LVC161.pdf) has a typical quiescent current of 0.1μA at 3.3V. Two of these in cascade would give you a 255 count for a total of 0.2μA.

To get the low current at 3.3V, the inputs must reach to VCC as shown in the additional supply current entry. See the image.

You will need additional LVC logic to detect a count of 100. This will push the current draw closer to 1μA or maybe well past.

I haven't tried it, but careful selection may get you closer to what you want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First one off the top of the list, SN74HC4060 Icc max 8uA at 25°C, Vcc = 6V. Is this not sufficient?

Typical will be ~nA, they just don't care to characterize it more tightly; these are currents low enough that it literally takes time to measure it more tightly, and more time on the test machine means higher production cost!

Current is also lower at lower Vcc, especially down in the subthreshold region (for 74HC, 2V or so).  Of course, at such low voltages, you'll need to think about how you're conditioning the input signals (what's it coming from, 5V logic? arbitrary?), and what you're able to drive with it (I<sub>OL</sub>/I<sub>OH</sub> will be very small; in contrast, say you're driving an LED at 20mA, even if it's 1 in 100 pulses, it massively exceeds the average consumption of logic, even at max Vcc and temp).

Comment: Thanks! I see Icc <80u for SN74HC4060 on the datasheet, page 3. And no value for typical consumption 
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc4060.pdf?ts=1697493329949&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fgoogle.com

The signal is 3.3V and at the moment it is driven by a multivibrator.
There are no LEDs or other extras, the entire system with many sensors, radio etc consumes a few hundred uW on average. Power is my main optimization parameter.